# WPF error : expected class , delegate, enum, inter

Tags: c#, wpf

```
namespace custontextbox
{
    public class Classtxtbox : TextBox
    {
        public TextBoxMask Mask { get; set; }

        public Classtxtbox()
        {
            this.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(Classtxtbox_TextChanged);
        }

        void Classtxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.CaretIndex = this.Text.Length;

            var tbEntry = sender as Classtxtbox;

            if (tbEntry != null && tbEntry.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                tbEntry.Text = formatNumber(tbEntry.Text, tbEntry.Mask);
            }
        }

        public static string formatNumber(string MaskedNum, TextBoxMask pfiger)
        {
            int x;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();

            if (MaskedNum != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < MaskedNum.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(MaskedNum.Substring(i, 1), out x))
                    {
                        sb.Append(x.ToString());
                    }
                }
                switch (pfiger)
                {
                    case TextBoxMask.SSN:
                    > error on this line !!!
                    ------------------------
                     return methods.FormatForSSN(sb.ToString());
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

    }

    public enum TextBoxMask
    {
        Phone7Digit,
        Phone7DigitWithExt,
        Phone10Digit,
        Phone10DigitWithExt,
        Phone11Digit,
        Phone11DigitWithExt,
        SSN
    }
}
```

---

### > crating another class for all the methods

**

> is there any other way to use this method in case ?

**

```
public class methods
{
    public static StringBuilder FormatForSSN(String sb)
    {
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        if (sb.Length > 0) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(0, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 1) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(1, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 2) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(2, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 3) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(3, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 6) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(6, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 7) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(7, 1));
        if (sb.Length > 8) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(8, 1));

        return sb2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your question and code to make question more readable

Comment: You can greatly simplify this: if the length is greater than 8, do `sb2.Substring(8, 1)`. Otherwise, do `sb2.Substring(sb.Length - 1, 1)`

Comment: Some more detail would be useful. For a start, can you post the text of the stacktrace if there is one, or the compiler error including any line numbers referencing the issue?

Comment: ok , i ll keep it in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormatForSSN` returns a `StringBuilder` but `formatNumber` returns a `string`. Either change the return type of `FormatForSSN` to `string`:

```
public static string FormatForSSN(String sb)
{
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    if (sb.Length > 0) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(0, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 1) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(1, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 2) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(2, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 3) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(3, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 6) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(6, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 7) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(7, 1));
    if (sb.Length > 8) sb2.Append(sb.Substring(8, 1));

    return sb2.ToString();
}
```

Or call `ToString()` on the returned `StringBuilder`:

```
return methods.FormatForSSN(sb.ToString()).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you :)
and Sorry for the improper format , this was my 1st time.